# java naming an object from an aspect of another object

Tags: java, object

I am trying to create an object named after an aspect of another object.  I assumed that I would need to change count.counts  value into a string in order for this to work but I cannot work out how to reference this in creating the new object.

This is the code i have;

```
    String no=Integer.toString(count.count);

        BattleCruiser =new BattleCruiser();
        EList.add(battle);

        count.count++;
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? What are you trying to do? Btw, there is no battlecruiser variable.

Comment: Trying to create the battlecruiser variable named after the String no.

Comment: You want to dynamically name a variable? That does not make any sense... how would you reference it then? If you want numbered variables, have a look at arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object does not have a name. We give names to **variables** so that we know what they point to, what they represent.

Dynamically name a variable does not seem very useful, since you need to reference it afterwards. If the reference is dynamic too, then why not use a data structure instead? For instance:

- If you're trying to give **numbers** to your variables, for instance `ship0`, `ship1`... then you can use an array `ships` instead, and access `ships[0]`, `ships[1]`.
- If you want more **general names** that reference objects, you can use a `Map<String,Object>` instead.

Comment: My original goal was to create an unknown number of new objects and put them into an arraylist that i could later pull out and use a for loop to alter asspects of each object but was under the impression that each variable in the arraylist would need a unique name.  My original idea though doesn't seem possible though.

Comment: The name of the variable you use at the moment you call `list.add(variable)` does not matter, actually. Only the reference to the object (the variable value) is stored in the list.

Comment: Thanks.  Thats answered my problem.